# Как сверстать и заставить работать такой выпадающий список?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите примеры верстки такого выпадающего списка, или подскажите плагин который имеет похожий стиль выполнения, пока не нашел похожего примера в интернете.

Comment: ul li кучу раз - спозиционировать и готово,

Comment: @W_0rld А сами-то пытались сделать? Покажите код.